# how to select only rows with maximum VID in a table with multiple VIDs and other fields?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a view in SQL server that gives me records of some games.it returns multiple records that belong to a game and they have same Gid but different version have different Vids like below

```
vid gid otherData(Platform)
2   1   PC
2   1   PC ...
3   1   X1
3   1   X2....
2   5   PC
2   5   PC ...
3   5   X1
3   5   X2....
```

how to use group by and select or something else to select these record only?

```
3   1   X1
3   1   X2....
3   5   X1
3   5   X2....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions using `GROUP BY`:

- With CTE:

  ```
  ;WITH HighestVIDByGID AS
  (
      SELECT
          V.gid,
          MaxVid = MAX(V.vid)
      FROM
          vYourView AS V
      GROUP BY
          V.gid
  )
  SELECT
      V.*
  FROM
      vYourView AS V
      INNER JOIN HighestVIDByGID AS M ON 
          V.gid = M.gid AND
          V.vid = M.MaxVid
  ```
- Using `INNER JOIN` with subquery:

  ```
  SELECT
      T.*
  FROM
      vYourView AS T
      INNER JOIN (
              SELECT
                  V.gid,
                  MaxVid = MAX(V.vid)
              FROM
                  vYourView AS V
              GROUP BY
                  V.gid
          ) AS M ON
              T.gid = M.gid AND
              T.vid = M.MaxVid
  ```
- Using `EXISTS`:

  ```
  SELECT
      T.*
  FROM
      vYourView AS T
  WHERE
      EXISTS (
          SELECT
              'max vid version'
          FROM
              vYourView AS V
          GROUP BY
              V.gid
          HAVING
              T.gid = V.gid AND
              T.vid = MAX(V.vid))
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You want `dense_rank()` :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
order by dense_rank() over (partition by gid order by vid desc);
```

**EDIT :**

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by gid order by vid desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: I like this approach as a clever trick for a less typing, but in reality it offers no advantage to the more commonly seen approach of placing the ranking function inside a subquery and limiting its value to 1 in the outer query. Shortening the query in this way may perform worse ([in my tests at least](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff655a309d6eaba9eb46b7ad98b9ff45)), makes it less clear what the intent is, and means that the results cannot be sorted without changing the meaning of the query (see the last two queries in my test).

Comment: @GarethD. . .  If the `OP` has performance concern then i will definitely choose other way. BTW, `OP` has not mentioned any performance concern.